# UISplitViewController's detailView (UIWebView) size on orientation change?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, orientation, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a UISplitViewController which has a UIWebView assigned to its detailedView. The problem is that the UIWebView's content it is not resizing when I change the orientation.

I have added the meta tag to the loaded html

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'>
```

and in a regular UIViewController works well. However in the UISplitViewController's detailedView has no effect. And it is the same UIViewController that works when not in the split view controller.

Does anyone know any workaround or fix for this?

Comment: Hi. I'm having exatly the same issue, but I don't want to solve it manually, I would like to read the bounds attribute of the detailed view and get the correct size...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by setting this meta tag instead:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=700'>
```

and I think It makes sense because this is the max width of the detailedView when used with UISplitViewController and not device-width